# Flex : Print the whole page where the flex application is located?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex

- Is it possible, and if it is - how to print the whole html page where the flex application is running ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use ExternalInterface to call JavaScript to print the page.  You can see a tutorial on how to do this here:

http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_How_to_print_in_Flex_using_browser_capabilities-11468.html

Comment: this doesnt print the things which contains flex object